# It is possible to perform click using javascript in headless browser as click() operation is not working in my case

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

It is possible to perform click using javascript in headless browser as click() operation is not working in my case. As click using javascript is working on Firefox browser but it is not working in headless browser I am getting below error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0] is undefined
Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:15:17'
System info: host: 'devui1.pdx.aws', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_95'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 5.41 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: 'Admin-HP', ip: '10.242.2.4', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false,databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=38.6.0,       platform=LINUX, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=be53c1d5-b50b-47d4-afba-e0c8e88517aa, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: be53c1d5-b50b-47d4-afba-e0c8e88517aa
```

Code:

```
try{

    WebElement Checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(strSelectChkBox));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Checkbox);

    oGeneric.sleepTimer(5);
    constant.objLogs.writeLog("Clicked on Variant filter check box ");
}
  catch (TimeoutException toe ){
    constant.objLogs.writeLog("Failed to Clicked on Variant ");
    throw(toe);
}
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Please find code mentioned above

Comment: Have you tried to perform click using Actions? should be like this: new Actions(webdriver).click(webElement).build().perform() - this click works a bit differently from standard one.

Comment: Yes I tried this method also but it is not working